# Does php-fpm use event loop (queue, select etc)

Tags: php, asynchronous

A friend of mine is trying to create a backend system with lots of http comet connections. In fact server needs to send event notifications to many concurrent clients (At least 200). I know opening so much thread concurrently is not feasible and maybe possible. So the solution is async programming, which can be implicit (uwsgi in python...) or explicit (asyncio, tornado...)
I guess they will face problems using php since it uses thread for each connection by default. Do I think right?

Comment: `php-fpm` uses `epoll` by default, if it can. You can specify the event interface in the `php-fpm.conf` file. FPM boots up a few processes which handle requests, there's no new thread per request like with Apache. After a few hundred requests are served by a subprocess managed by FPM, it's killed and rebooted to clean any memory leaks caused by bad programming. The thread-per-connection was never what PHP used at all. It was Apache that booted up a PHP process in its own thread. Basically - your friend is safe if he uses PHP-FPM.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that `php-fpm` is behind a web server usually. It will depend (hugely) on how the web server handles concurrency. If your friend uses `nginx` then `nginx` can easily distribute the HTTP requests to a pool of `php-fpm` servers where each can handle `X` amount of users. However, 200 is not that huge of a deal, even a 1000 shouldn't be an issue with today's hardware.

Comment: Is your question related to how `php-fpm` works or how to perform efficient asynchronous code using php as a language? That's a bit unclear and if you can clarify it a bit, a proper answer can be provided. However, it would be nice to have your friend included in providing the details.